# Unity Rendering one frame in VR and then giving up?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I'm making a VR game in unity using OpenXR using the standard built in render pipeline, and when i start it with steamvr on it tells me its waiting for the game, shows one frame, and then flickers between that frame and the waiting screen forever.

When I check the profiler it looks like theres only being one frame drawn. in the editor I can still move the camera and see the updated position though. What's weird is this worked a bit ago and I dont know if I changed something somehow I mean the only thing I did was add some code to move the camera and change a material on the floor

The following is my camera settings on the VR rig main camera

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM2pF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I HAD THE GAME PAUSED  to fix it you unpress the pause button next to the play button